# Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2010 look more like VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Specifically, I don't like the tab arrows that are shown when "View White Space" is enabled... they're too big and obtrusive. VS 2008 is more subtle.

Thanks!

Comment: Please vote for change at: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=514853