# Visual Studio 2008 theme for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i'm working on Visual Studio 2008 for a long time and i like the default theme of VS2008. But when working with Visual Studio 2010 the default color scheme look different and i really don't like it. I found [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/changing-visual-studios-color-palette/) to change the color scheme but there are no ready style look like VS2008, anyone can suggest me a link to download VS2008 style for VS2010 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find the below blog useful:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeTheVisualStudio2010IDEColorsLookLikeVisualStudio2008.aspx

In addition if found the following styles for vs2010 to look like vs2008:

https://studiostyl.es/schemes/search?q=vs2008

Keep in my mind you need to install vs extension as prerequisite - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378/

**Update**: Since the above links haven't satisfied the answer, I'm adding another source I've found to support the question.

The following link help you change your visual studio 2010 to looks like 2008.

https://jesonmartajaya.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/c-how-to-make-vs2010-look-and-feel-like-vs2008/

Source: [Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2010 look more like VS 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779531/is-there-a-way-to-make-visual-studio-2010-look-more-like-vs-2008)

Comment: Yes, i found these blog thread before you, but the theme included does not look like Vs2008. I'd like some way to convert VS2010 look same as Vs2008 as much as possible